# How to release Linux lock files for unique daemon process and multiple users

Tags: c, linux, locking, daemon, flock

I have a deamon of which only one instance should be running at a time. The daemon is part of a larger application. I made this happen this way:

- `open()` `/tmp/prog.pid` with `O_CREAT | O_RDWR`, permissions 0666. The permissions actually become 0664, probably because of umask (?)
- `flock()` on the file descriptor returned by `open()`, with `LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB`

This is all I had first. My daemon exits on `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT`, but it turned out that the lock was not released upon exit. I realized with help of `man 1 flock` (strangely not in `man 2 flock`) that manually unlocking might be necessary if "the enclosed command group may have forked a background process which should not be holding the lock". This is exaclty the case since I am working on a daemon, so I now unlock manually at exit.

Now to my problem: there are several users who might be running the daemon.

If user1 is running the daemon, I want user2 to be able to kill it and restart it as themselves.

The locked file `/tmp/prog.pid` has permissions 0664, owner user1, group user1.

A stop script `prog_stop` kills all the processes involved in the application (it requires superuser rights, I'm ok with that). It also kills the daemon. When user2 runs `prog_stop`, the lock is released (I believe), but user2 **cannot start its own daemon process**, because it is neither owner of the lock file, nor in its group.

Several possible solutions:

- make the lock file 0666, writeable to all. Dangerous.
- create a group in which users need to be in order to run the application. This requires that all users start the application with this group, probably with help of `newgrp`. Easy to forget, not easy to enforce that people do this. Possibly set the current group in the scripts used to start the application?
- completely delete the lock file in `prog_stop`. Drawback: I open the file from a C file, where the path string is defined. I need to write (and maintain!) the exact same file name with path in the stop script.

Lock files for daemons must be very common. What is the standard way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way for lock files is to turn the daemon into a service and require `sudo` (or becoming `root` by other means) to start and stop it.

Now you can give the file a certain group; users in this group can then modify it. They can use `newgrp` but it's better to add them to the group with `usermod --append --groups=foo bar` (to add user `bar` to the group `foo`; the user keeps her original GID and all other groups they had). After a relog, you can validate this with `id bar`.

This is all very tedious. When I need something like that, I create a socket. Sockets are killed with the process that created them (so no cleanup necessary). Sockets can also be used to communicate with the running daemon (give me your status, shutdown, maybe even restart, ...).

I'm using a default port number which I compile into the application but I also use an environment variable to override the default.

Just make sure that you create a socket which listens on `localhost`; otherwise anyone on the Internet might be able talk to it.

Comment: I meant to use `newgrp`, not to add the user to a new group (I use `usermod -a -G <group> <user>`), but to *make the group the current one*. By default, if <user> creates a file, it is owned by <user> and for *group* <user>. The user has to make this special group their current group for created files to have it as group. Try `touch asdf` and `ll asdf`, then `newgrp tty`, `touch qwer`, `ll qwer`.

Comment: I'd use `chown(path,uid,gid)` in the daemon to give the file the correct group or run the daemon with the correct group in the first place. No need for `newgrp`.